# What is the Main differences between consultant role and Contractor Role?

Tags: contractors, consultants

I am currently working as contractor to the client from Outsourcing Organization. I have got a latest job offer from consulting organization. And the role is consultant. Here my question is What is the main difference between consultant role and contractor role?

Comment: As explained [in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/12226011#12226011): *"I do not think this is a good question, as 'contractor' describes a type of worker (someone who works on a contract-basis), while 'consultant' describes a type of role (and has nothing to do with what type of worker you are). You could be a contracted consultant, and then there is no difference."*

Answer (score 2):

You would need to ask the company making the offer this question.  In fact, it's a little concerning that you got through the entire interview process to the point that the company has offered you a job without, apparently, having a conversation about what specifically you would be doing.

Job titles on their own are rather meaningless-- they mean as little or as much as the company intends them to mean.  Some companies will use "contractor" and "consultant" interchangeably.  Others will make a distinction between the titles.  Exactly what that distinction is, however, is very dependent on the company.

Comment: Agreed! I think there is an implication that a "consultant" from a "consulting organization" is providing some more expertise than a "contractor" from an "outsourcing organization", who may just be a warm body. But it's just an implication, not a fact.

Answer (score 0):

These terms are used interchangeably, and before assuming any specific meaning you should get in touch with the company making the offer. But generally speaking the difference is

Consultant brings in necessary knowledge about the concerned business and guides the investment of the client. They do make projections like expected recurring income to client after x time and money investment.Most of the resources are hired by the client under the guidance of consultant.

Contractor on other hand undertakes to complete a task under given time period for a agreed cost. The resources are brought in by contractor and belong to contractor.

following links can shed more light

1. [First discussion](http://www.thisboundlessworld.com/travel-for-work-consulting-vs-contracting#)
2. [Second discussion](http://www.itworld.com/ITW344)

Comment: Strictly speaking *consultant* is a term describing "a professional who provides professional or expert advice" (Wikipedia), i.e. it is about **content**, a *contractor* is a term describing the working **relationship** (someone you hire 'by contract'). They have indeed been used interchangeably and that does not help ;-)

Comment: Also sector specific ...in IT yes very thin line but not that thin in case of industries involved with tangible objects like construction where the difference is very prominent

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out in other responses, these are really not interchangeable, however a better question might be 'what is the difference between a developer and a consultant?'.

If a customer hires you on contract to write or maintain an application, then you are basically acting in a 'developer' role to modify code.  Your services as a 'consultant' are incidental - the customer pretty much knows what they want and they've told you what to do.

The customer could also hire you on contract to tell them what they need.  In this situation you are a 'consultant'. At that point you start looking at their workflow, their business process, the distribution of tasks among workers, etc. to find disconnects, inefficiencies, duplicated efforts, or unnecessary steps.  As you find these you document them, and at some point you identify what should be done, which may or may not involve software or other forms of automation.  At that point the customer may decide to employ a developer, or they might ask you to develop some or all of the solution.